# Display name instead of the id in angular material table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table

I used a material table as a reusable component. I call it in other component as followed.

```
class UserTable {
  name: string;
  vehicleId: number;
  garageId: number;
}

tableColumns: Array<Column> = [
    {
      columnDef: 'name',
      header: 'Name',
      cell: (element: Record<string, unknown>) => `${element['name']}`
    },
    {
      columnDef: 'vehicleId',
      header: 'Vehicle',
      cell: (element: Record<string, unknown>) => {
        const vehicle = this.vehicleList.find(vehicles => vehicles.id === element['vehicleId']);
        return vehicle?.name;
      }
    },
    {
      columnDef: 'garageId',
      header: 'Garage',
      cell: (element: Record<string, unknown>) => {
        const garage = this.garageList.find(garages => garages.id === element['garageId']);
        return garage?.name;
      }
    }
  ];
```

the User class

```
class User implements IUser {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  vehicleId: number;
  garageId: number;
}
```

I need to display name, vehicle Name, garage in the table. to display vehicle name, i used above code. It works, but give console error '*Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')*' and can't visible the garage name also. 
what can i do for that?

Comment: Can you please add a stackBlitz here with your code ?

Comment: looks like `this.vehicleList` is undefined. Where does `vehicleList` come from?

Answer (score 0):

As per [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), arrow functions don't have binding to `this` and hence should not be used as methods on an object. And that's exactly what you're doing.

What this means is that `this.vehicleList` is probably not what you expect it to be - i.e. it reads the `vehicleList` property of the caller of the function, for which it's probably not defined.

Take a look at the below example for better understanding:

```js
let def = {
  value: 'value in def',
  logValue: () => {
    // You expect this will log `value in def`, but it won't. 
    console.log(this.value)
  }
};

this.value = 'value in global scope';
console.log(def.logValue());
```

You should probably read more about [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) to understand it better.

You might want to switch the arrow function into [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) and see if it solves your scoping issues.